# Trying to split a tsv file into two by looking for an empty line

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use pandas to split a tsv file that looks something like this:

x y

x y

[empty row]

x y z a b c

x y z a b c

into 2 separate dataframes with one containing the half before the empty line, and one containing the rest of the file - this is because I can't read the whole file into one dataframe as the two portions have a different amount of columns.

Is there a way I can establish the empty row as a "stopping point" for the first dataframe, and read the rest of the tsv file into another dataframe?

Currently, I'm solving this by just skipping lines using pd.read_csv(file_name, skiprows = 3, delimiter = '\t'), but using this method is not a very good approach.

Thanks!

Comment: you could use standard open(), read(), write(), close() to split it into two files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First, you need to read your file as a whole to a df. Do not skip blank lines, this will read the blank lines as `NaN`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter='\t', skip_blank_lines=False)
```

Now, identify the empty row and create separate groups in the df.

```
df['emptyrow'] = df.isnull()
df['group'] = (df['emptyrow'] != df['emptyrow'].shift()).cumsum()
groups = df.groupby(by='group')
```

With this, we have groups within df which can be accessed using `groups.get_group(key)`.
Also, we can have a dict of data frames for each group key.

```
split_dfs = {}
for grp in groups.groups.keys():
    split_dfs[grp] = groups.get_group(grp).drop(['emptyrow','group'], axis=1)
```

Now, `split_dfs` is a dict of dfs each with a subset of the original df based on the group we created.

Comment: I can't read the whole file without generating a Parser Error - specifically "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 27, saw 527". Would using a try except approach to ignore the error be an apt approach for this case?